# Evaluate the following by converting to the definite integral

Tags: calculus, limits, summation

Me and my classmates have been unable to answer this problem from our homework

$$\lim\limits_{n\to+\infty}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac k{n^2+k^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Simply rearrange as:
$$
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac k{n^2+k^2}=\lim\limits_{n\to+\infty}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac {k/n}{(n/n)^2+(k/n)^2}1/n
$$
which you will recognize as the definition of the Riemann integral for $f(x)=\frac{x}{1+x^2}$ between $\frac kn|_{k=0}=0$ and $\frac kn|_{k=n}=1$, noting the Riemann intervals are selected at the end.
$$
=\int_0^1\frac {x}{1+x^2}dx=\frac12\ln(1+x^2)\bigg|_0^1=\frac12\ln(2)
$$

Comment: Answering other students' homework problems for them when they have not shown any of their own work is a clear violation of our Community Guidelines.